# InputStreamReader encoder

Tags: java, encoding, inputstreamreader

My problem is fairly simple:

```
new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
```

Makes β and ・look like question marks.

Which encoder should I use to see those characters correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from [The Java 5.0 Charset documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html).

```
Charset     Description
US-ASCII    Seven-bit ASCII, a.k.a. ISO646-US, a.k.a. the Basic Latin block of the Unicode character set
ISO-8859-1  ISO Latin Alphabet No. 1, a.k.a. ISO-LATIN-1
UTF-8       Eight-bit UCS Transformation Format
UTF-16BE    Sixteen-bit UCS Transformation Format, big-endian byte order
UTF-16LE    Sixteen-bit UCS Transformation Format, little-endian byte order
UTF-16      Sixteen-bit UCS Transformation Format, byte order identified by an optional byte-order mark
```

So try all of these strings in your second parameter until you get the desired encoding.

Comment: In the end it was ISO-8859-15. Thank you very much guys!

Answer (score 5):

You should use whichever encoding your input data is *really* in. We can't tell you that for you, although if you provide the *bytes* which are meant to represent those characters, we may be able to suggest some possibilities.

While you can sometimes apply some heuristics to guess at an encoding, you *really* should know it based on where the data is coming from. In this case you haven't given us any hint whatsoever what your input is - if it's from a web response, you should look at the `Content-Type` header of the response. If it's from a file, it really depends on what produced that file.

EDIT: Now we know that it *is* a web response, you don't have to go header-diving yourself, of course. You can use an HTTP client library which will download the data for you and decode it as a string itself.

Comment: Well, the data is coming from a wiki page from the internet, so I don't really know what encoding they are using.

Comment: @santirivera92: As per my answer, look at the Content-Type header. Or use an HTTP client library which does this for you...

Comment: @santirivera92 : if you are using `URLConnection` then you can get Content-Type using `URLConnection.getHeaderFieldKey("Content-type")` and `URLConnection.getHeaderField("Content-type")`

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to what the others said the final result is going to be UTF-8 while in Java, and that's going to be able to handle any characters you have. However, the question here is how do you *read* it, and that depends on what encoding the file is written in which, apparently, is not UTF-8.